# Any way to get the physical file for ITLibMediaItem?

Tags: swift, macos, swift5, itunes

I'm new to Swift, back when I did iPhone development it was Objective-C only. And as far as writing for the Mac goes, I'm mainly a Windows developer. So forgive me if the answer is obvious, but I'm trying to create a tool for myself that will download all of my iTunes library (which is currently all in the cloud) and stick it on an external hard drive. I can get the library metadata easily enough, but I can't seem to find a way to get the actual file for the ITLibMediaItem.

For fun, here is my current chunk of code. Really just coding in a sandbox app trying some things currently.

```
let library = try? ITLibrary(apiVersion: "1.1")
let songs = library?.allMediaItems
for item in songs! {
    if (item.mediaKind != ITLibMediaItemMediaKind.kindPodcast && item.mediaKind != ITLibMediaItemMediaKind.kindTVShow)
    {
        print("Song title: \(item.title)")
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I tried, `ITLibMediaItem`'s property `location` will be `nil` whenever `cloud` set to `YES` and `locationType` will be set to  `ITLibMediaItemLocationTypeRemote`. 

That means we dont get any location when the files are in the cloud - IIUC then there is nothing we can do with such files from this API's perspective.